# SQL not showing data when executing the script

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have database. Recently added two rows to the database from third party software

**1)** When I executed below script it not listing updated data which executed recently by third party software. But showing old data.

```
Select  top 5000 [T_idx]  ,[T_TAG]   ,[T_Date] from [house].[dbo].[total]
```

**2)** When I execute below code it script it showing updated data which was executed recently by third party software.

```
Select * from [house].[dbo].[total]
where T_TAG like '%HO%' order by T_Date DESC
```

Comment: MS SQL Server or MySQL?

Comment: `SELECT * TOP 5000` is syntactically incorrect in both MySQL and SQL Server.

Comment: But when i am executing * Top 5000 ...  ,, in SQL table data showing as per the script but it's not the latest data,

Comment: SQL Server is not automatically sorting according to your wishes. You need to add the `ORDER BY` to make it sort properly.

Comment: @venkat TOP keyword bring TOP data and it's not the latest data in your table , order your rows in descending and select TOP 5000 rows or use limit keyword.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to order it correctly (if you want it in date order that is):

```
SELECT
  TOP 5000 [T_idx], [T_TAG], [T_Date]
FROM
  [house].[dbo].[total]
ORDER BY
  T_Date DESC
```

Comment: I tried above one and the results are 5000 rows are effected, msg 9002, Lvel17, State 6, Line 1 .... the Log file for database 'tempdb' is full. Backup the transaction log for the database to freeup some log space.                                                                                how i can free up some space ??? where i can find 'tempdb' file ??

Comment: Ooops... that's a totally different question and is the sql server telling you that you're out of space in the tempdb. You will have to truncate the tempdb... look online for the answer.

Comment: i found the file named 'tempdb.mdf' but how could i delete some info from the file ??

Comment: yes, it showing the message, it's a large database !!! , daily transactions are updating the SQL continuously

Comment: Read this http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307487. The tempdb is however growing for a reason. As the name states it is a database with temporary data. According to the needs of your apps or other work hitting the tempdb you should make sure tempdb can grow. If you get this issue you can try to shrink it but if it grows back up again you'll either need to accept that it is the size required (buy more disk) or change your code to not use tempdb as much.

Comment: Also check if the tempdb is set to simple recovery model in the database settings... that will help the database to be emptied automatically.

Comment: When i am executing above script with top 10, i am not getting latest data with respect to the date. :(

Answer (score 1):

top 5000 will only show the first 5000 records. quite possibly the new records are not part of that. remove `top 5000`

Comment: New records are part of the Database and when executing below script it not listing the new records

Comment: @venkat Use Order By [T_Date] DESC and select TOP 5000 ,it will fetch your data or you can use LIMIT 5000 .